# Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine troubleshooting

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

is anyone experiencing issue with the Google Kubernetes Engine (specifically in us-central1-b region - April 3rd 11pm EST)
I'm not able to to see my workload or any of my cluster configurations in the Google Kubernetes Engine section, it is intermittent (one minute is there then disappears)

Also can't connect to the Kubernetes section of the Google Cloud Console to check on my pods !!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: StackOverflow is not the best place to ask questions about issues on platforms. A better way is to ask about status of your environment in Google Cloud Support and also try to check it here - https://status.cloud.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

No information of any issues as far as I can see. Could have been a network connection issue on your side, please check.

It appears to me that this is some issue about getting metadata from the cluster. You could check the following to help you troubleshoot or see if there is any underlying problems:

```
$ docker info 
$ docker version 
$ kubectl version
$ gcloud container clusters describe <your-cluster-name-) --zone <your-cluster-zone>
$ kubectl get componentstatuses
```

Comment: that's what's weird about there were no information reported about it on google cloud status page! I called them but since I only have the bronze package I got the billing support they told me they're going to have a technician check it then let me know but I only got an email a 24hr later asking me to upgrade the package if I want an explanation from a technician!! I have other clusters setup exactly the same way and nothing happened to them, only that one for some unknown reasons was shut down and took all night to recover because in the morning that cluster was running fine.

Comment: I have no information that users have reported a similar issue like you're having so I suspect it is related to your local network or system. Kubernetes dashboard appears to be working fine. Could you share any errors that you get from the connection?

Comment: I attached some screens shots there, it starts with when no workload is showing there for a long time(picture #1), then little bit later a portion of workload is showing with missing data unavailable notification(picture #2), at last all the workload will be showing for a brief second(picture #3)! then everything disappears again and back to picture #1! Kept doing that all night and then it did recover and went back to normal state in the morning!